# Jmeter Mail support

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to check my gmail with a mail reader sampler in jmeter and enabled both imap and pop3 in my gmail account.

Everytime I try to connect to gmail, I keep getting this error:

```
Response message: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: imap.gmail.com, 993; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
imaps://xyz@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com/INBOX[1]
```

I tried both SSL and TLS option at the bottom. I tried adding and leaving out the port.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good (given you tick `Use SSL` radio) , most likely you are sitting behind a corporate proxy server so JMeter is not able to establish connection with the IMAP Gmail endpoint.

You can configure JMeter to use proxy for Internet access as described in [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) User Manual chapter, just launch it as:

```
jmeter -H proxy_host -P proxy_port ...
```

For more information on working with email protocols in JMeter tests check out [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article

Comment: We try also suggested method, but it is not working. There is problem of connection timeout,Not in connection estabilation